# Readonlyrest and Kibana Permission Configuration

Tags: security, elasticsearch, readonly

I'm trying to setup a basic readonlyrest example with Kibana. My config is as follows:

```
readonlyrest:
enable: true
response_if_req_forbidden: Forbidden by ReadonlyREST ES plugin

access_control_rules:

- name: Accept requests from users in group team1 on index1
  type: allow
  hosts: [localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.0.0/24]
  groups: ["team1"]
  actions: ["indices:data/read","indices:data/read/mge/*","indices:data/read/mget","indices:data/read/*","indices:data/write/*","indices:admin/template/*","indices:admin/create", "cluster:monitor/*"]
  indices: ["<no-index>", ".kibana*", "logstash*", "default" ,"sha*" ,"ba*"]

users:

- username: alice
  auth_key: alice:p455phrase
  groups: ["team1"]
```

Unfortunately this does not work. I keep getting Authorization exception with the following error message in elasticsearch logs:

```
no block has matched, forbidding by default: { action: indices:data/read/mget, 
OA:127.0.0.1, indices:[.kibana], M:POST, P:/_mget, C:{"docs":[{"_index":".kibana",
"_type":"config","_id":"4.6.1"}]}, Headers:[]}
```

What is missing in my config?

In kibana.yml the configuration is:

```
elasticsearch.username: "alice"
elasticsearch.password: "p455phrase"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use case is a basic kibana authentication, you should follow [the example in the documentation](https://github.com/beshu-tech/readonlyrest-docs/blob/master/multiuser_guide.md).

Once you get that working, you could modify the example to assign the required rules to groups, and groups to your hard-coded users.

Keep in mind that this will not be a production ready solution, due to the crappy security level offered by HTTP basic auth between browser and Kibana:

1. The browser will pass the credentials unencrypted at every request
2. No way for the user to "logout" from Kibana

Nowadays ReadonlyREST Offers two Kibana plugins ([PRO](http://readonlyrest.com/pro) and [Enterprise](http://readonlyrest.com/enterprise)), which fixes the above limitations using encrypted cookies, and injecting a logout button into the Kibana UI.

The 30 days trial is available for [download](https://readonlyrest.com/download/)

Comment: Thanks. The basic kibana examples works if I allow ALL indices and all actions. But what I want to do is restrict Kibana's access to indices that start with sha and those that start with ba. To achieve this, I added    indices: ["<no-index>", ".kibana", ".kibana/*", "default" ,"sha*" ,"ba*"]. And this results in permission error. no block has matched, forbidding by default: { action: indices:data/read/search, OA:127.0.0.1, indices:[shakespeare sha*], M:POST, P:/_msearch, C:{"index":["sha*"],"ignore_unavailable":true}...

Comment: I did some more digging. It appears that readonlyrest is working as expected.  It seems when kibana starts, it makes one or many requests with the logstash patterrn. And if the user does not have read access on logstash-*, access is denied. So the question now is how do I prevent kibana from making this initial requests with logstash index pattern?

Comment: Try this: start kibana with the plugin disabled, change the `logstash-*` index pattern, re-enable the plugin, Kibana should know what to look for without defaulting to looking for `logstash-*`

Comment: Sorry. I am not finding how to disable plugins on kibana 4.6. No such property in kibana.yml, no list of plugins in kibana.yml, installedPlugins folder empty,  "./bin/kibana plugin --list" returns nothing. Though according to this ticket, it should be possible: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/7241.

Comment: no no I meant disable readonlyrest plugin for elasticsearch! There's an `enable: true` at the beginning of the configuration :)

Comment: Unfortunately my use case is such that I have to stop and start kibana many many times a day while Elasticsearch continues to run. Any hint on where to patch kibana if I wanted to change that default logstash-* pattern?

Comment: kibana state is saved in ES in a special index called `.kibana`. That's why I was saying: let kibana save its configuration (included the index pattern) ONCE with the ES security disabled (or configure a login with `kibana_access: rw` for some super user). Then read-only users should see the dashboards just fine

Comment: The link is dead, any reference ?