# Installing readonlyrest plugin for elasticsearch getting error FileNotFoundException

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to install elastisearch [elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin](https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin). Now on its installation page [Install,-Uninstall,-Build](https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/wiki/Install,-Uninstall,-Build) it was mentioned to use command   `sudo bin/plugin install https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/raw/master/download/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-v1.5_es-v2.1.1.zip`.

I tried to use above command but got error

```
-> Installing from https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/raw/master/download/elasticse
arch-readonlyrest-v1.5_es-v2.1.1.zip...
Trying https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/raw/master/download/elasticsearch-readonl
yrest-v1.5_es-v2.1.1.zip ...
Failed: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/raw/master/downloa
d/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-v1.5_es-v2.1.1.zip]; nested: FileNotFoundException[https://github.com/sscarduzio/el
asticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/raw/master/download/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-v1.5_es-v2.1.1.zip];
```

I also tried to download the plugin from this url [download](https://readonlyrest.com/#download), and also got an email from them where it was mentioned to use below steps.

- `Download the zip file cd to the Elasticsearch home`
- `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///download-folder/readonlyrest-1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip`
- `Edit elasticsearch.yml and add your configuration snippets`

So i downloaded my readonlyrest plugin but when i tried to use command `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///download-folder/readonlyrest-1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip` i got below error

```
-bash: bin/elasticsearch-plugin: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please tell me what is the proper way to install elasticsearch readonlyrest plugion in my elasticsearch-cluster properly i am trying from last three days and haven't found anything useful.

**UPDATE**

I used below command but still got an error

```
sum1er99@elasticsearch-2-1-vm:/usr/share/elasticsearch$ sudo bin/plugin install https://github.com/sscarduzio/el
asticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/archive/v1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip
-> Installing from https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/archive/v1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip..
.
Trying https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/archive/v1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip ...
Downloading ....................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
................................................................................................................
..........................................................DONE
Verifying https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/archive/v1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip checksums 
if available ...
NOTE: Unable to verify checksum for downloaded plugin (unable to find .sha1 or .md5 file to verify)
ERROR: Could not find plugin descriptor 'plugin-descriptor.properties' in plugin zip
sum1er99@elasticsearch-2-1-vm:/usr/share/elasticsearch$
```

Comment: What version of ES do you have?

Comment: What if you use this link: https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/archive/v1.13.1_es2.4.4.zip ?

Comment: @Val please see updated post where i ran your command and still got error.

Comment: I am using ES 2.4.4

Comment: Hey i just looked at this issue which was ame like me and it completely solved my problem https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin/issues/153

Comment: @Val can you please look at my new question may be you could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056188/in-elasticsearch-where-to-generate-keystore-and-add-authentication-in-readonlyre

Comment: Please use the official website for downloads, stay WELL AWAY from obsolete versions of security software in general, Including ReadonlyREST. https://readonlyrest.com

Answer (score 1):

The downloads policy of ReadonlyREST has changed, you can't install by url anymore (unless you host the zip file somewhere yourself).

I will repeat here what I said in GitHub issue #153:

I opted to have an [official website as a single point of download](https://readonlyrest.com) for various reasons:

- keep track of the number of downloads in google analytics (GH has no analytics for downloads)
- keep track of unique users downloads (same reasons as above)
- keep track of what versions are downloaded most (useful to decide when old ES branches can become unsupported)
- Guarantee that users can download ONLY the latest version (this is a security plugin, and this is important)
- Be able to notify users when a vulnerability is fixed and you should upgrade

Comment: Sorry but what i did was the `url you mailed me` when i clicked on download button, i used that url and then it got downloaded successfully. Is my installation right or not ??

Comment: If it installed successfully, even from the url in the email, you're good.

Comment: I am getting error while installing it from zip file, here is the error ERROR: Unknown plugin /home/monitoring-server/readonlyrest-1.16.6_es5.3.2(1).zip

Comment: `bin/elasticsearch-plugin install file:///download-folder/readonlyrest-1.16.6_es5.3.2.zip `