# In Elasticsearch where to generate keystore and add authentication in readonlyrest plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to add password authentication in my elasticsearch cluster using [readonlyrest](https://github.com/sscarduzio/elasticsearch-readonlyrest-plugin) plugin. I installed the plugin successfully now i am trying to configure my configuration file(.yml file) but there In case 0 they are using a keystore see below

```
http.type: ssl_netty4
readonlyrest:
enable: true

ssl:
  enable: true
  keystore_file: "/elasticsearch/plugins/readonlyrest/keystore.jks"
  keystore_pass: readonlyrest
  key_pass: readonlyrest
```

Can anyone please tell me from where i can `generate this keystore` and also `where is the username and password authentication parameters set in this plugin`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) to generate a valid SSL certificate for free.

Use Letsencrypt's own tool called [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org)

A Letsencrypt certificate works just fine in ReadonlyREST, but first you have to [convert  it into a JKS keystore](https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm).

Obtaining a JKS keystore from Letsencrypt certs is a common procedure:  you would do the same if you want to use Letsencrypt with Tomcat. A very common, googleable use case.

PS: I will progressively release some detailed documentation in the following weeks on the [official website](https://readonlyrest.com).